# jQuery setTimeout not working with version 1.7

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm using this script below which works when using with jQuery 1.4 but not with 1.7.2:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
      if ($('#hpnews').length > 0) {
        $('#hpnews').fadeIn('slow');
      }
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Does any one now why it's not working?

Thanks

Comment: why do you think it is `setTimeout` issue? Does it work if you remove `setTimeout`?

Comment: Does `setTimeout` fire immediately, and then every 3000 milliseconds after? If so you'd probably need a `$(document).ready()` in there, at least for the first (or maybe second) iteration.

Comment: @beneverard Answer my own question, it waits until 3000 milliseconds before the first fire... still might be good to put document ready in there though.

Answer (score 0):

So `setTimeout` only fires once, and waits until 3000 milliseconds to do so.

Are you sure you're DOM is completely ready by that point?

Try the following:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        setTimeout(function(){
            if ($('#hpnews').length > 0) {
                $('#hpnews').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }, 3000);

    });

</script>
```

Also, it may be handy to put an `alert()` in there too, just to make sure it's definitely firing.

**Edit**

As per your comment of $ not being a function, the chances are the $ variable is being overwritten by another framework (or similar), one of the following methods will resolve this issue.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready() // use $j instead of $

jQuery(document).ready() // or use the actual jQuery var
```

Comment: yeah its still not working i added the alert() but nothing came up, it does work if i add jquery 1.4 but this effects offer stuff.

Comment: Could it be that am using the layerslider in wordpress ?

Comment: What do you get in the console when you `console.log($('#hpnews').length)` before your if statement?

Comment: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Hmmm, that means jQuery has not been set, are you setting jQuery *above* the script you're running above?

Comment: yes, JQuery is loading at the top of the page this script is inline down the bottom of the page

Comment: Have you got any other JavaScript libraries running, ones that perhaps might hijack the $ variable? MooTools does this, as well as others perhaps? To test, change all $ to jQuery, such as this: `jQuery('document').ready( ...`